# Exporting cell and numeric data from a for loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Good night
I have two files, one containing numerical data and other with numeric/cell data (names).
Lets say

File 1 = Cell and Numeric Data
File 2 = Just numeric Data

File 1 =

```
name[cell] - lastname[cell] - library number
helena          some               23363
ana             thing              55556
alice            else               8858
.
.
.
```

File 2 =

```
library number - numberofbooks - bookcode
23363              10               66585
55556              32               66585
8858               2222             66585
.
.
.
```

What I have to do is match the book code and export a file that contains all the variables.

My main problem is export cell data with numerical data, I was using `fprintf` but the `%c` and `%s` don't work with `fprintf`.

any help would be great

Comment: "match the book code" with what. In File1 there is no book code. Maybe you want to match the two files using library number?

Comment: you can paste the code with fprintf that doesn't work so that we can understand what exactly you are trying to do.